# Regular expression for decmal value

Tags: .net, regex, c#-4.0

I want a regular expression which takes the following on the textbox key-down event for a decimal value

Condition

1. can enter max of only 7 integral part.
2. can enter max of 2 decimal part.
3. 12 character including comma separation for every thousand & single decimal character (1,000,000.00) but should be able to edit from 12 characters.

Possible formats can be,

- 9999999
- 9999998.55
- 9999998.5
- 0.55
- .55
- 1.5
- 21.22
- 2.
- empty''
- 3
- 0.00
- 1,234567.10
- 12,34567.00

etc.

or

A regex expression excluding comma complexity (satisfying only condition 1 & 2), which I can handle in code. I tried several regular expression, but couldn't find the exact one I needed.

I tried the below code but it is not working in keydown event for me.

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        bool isMatch = Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text,@"^(?!.*[\w-[\d]])  
                       (?=[\d.,]{0,12})  
                       (?=,{0,2})       
                       (?=\.{0,1})       
                       [\s\d]           
                       [\d,]{0,8}        
                       .?                
                       \d{0,2}           
                       \s?               
                        $");
       if (!isMatch)
       {
           e.Handled = e.Key != Key.Back;
       }
    }
```

Comment: OK, we know what you need. Question is, what have you tried already?

Comment: I tried some regex  from some stackoverflow post but didnot give me wat I needed, I tried to tweak it but didnot work for me also I am not good in creating new one as I have time constraint...!!!

Comment: What is `empty"`, do you mean a space value for empty or null?

Comment: do you need exactly one regexp? Can you use some logic with several regexps?

Comment: @OmegaMan both space & null!.

Comment: @YuriyKovalev yes I can try!

Comment: You should only use a versioned c# tag if the question is specific to that version.

Comment: @RyanGates your supposition does not matter. The .Net regular expression parser has not been changed since .Net 2, so most modern .Net versions handle the pattern the same.

Comment: @OmegaMan granted, but then what is the correct tag that signifies "most modern .Net versions"?

Comment: @neo Are the formats you list above all valid?  If so, you don't seem to be requiring commas as thousand separators -- at least in US, they would be every third digit.

Comment: @OmegaMan Its not taking input to the textbox in keydown event after giving the regular expression as above.

Comment: @neo I edited the code and provided examples.

Comment: @neo Please be aware that the 7-digit & 2-comma rule is impossible to enforce with regex alone. The provided code still does not satisfy your conditions. See the comments in the answer for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This pattern won't catch someone from entering an incomplete number such as (1,2) but will allow for the numbers you requested as well as a space. Null has to be caught before the passing it on.

```
 ^                # Work from the start of the line
 (?!.*[\w-[\d]])   # Don't allow any Alphanumerics (A-Za-z\d) but except digits \d
 (?=[\d.,]{0,12})  # Only allow for 0-12 digits or commas or periods
 (?!\d{8,})        # Stop match if eight consecutive digits found
 (?![\d,]{9,})     # Stop match if a combination of digits and commas exceeds 9
 [\s\d.]           # Allow for a space or a number period and consume it to the match.
 [\d,]{0,8}        # Should find numbers or a comma for up to 8 items
 .?                # A possible period
 \d{0,2}           # Two digits possible after the period
 \s?               # A space character (\r\n?) may be found or even an extra space (allowed per rules)
$
```

To use this pattern one must use the option IgnorePatternWhitespace which simply means the regex parser ignores spaces and comments in the pattern. It has no bearing on the processing. Use it as follows

```
Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace)
```

Here is my test program

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Negative Tests - Only False returned in this section"); 
        Console.WriteLine("12345678.00".IsMatch()); // False ->
        Console.WriteLine("123456789.00".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("123a4567.00".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("123.4567.00".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine ("1234567,8.00".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine ("1,234567,8.00".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine ("1,234567,.00".IsMatch());

        Console.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine);
        Console.WriteLine("Positive Tests - Only True returned in this section");
        Console.WriteLine("1234".IsMatch());  // True ->
        Console.WriteLine("9999998.55".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("9999998.5".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("0.55".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine(".55".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("1.5".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("21.22".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("2.".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("3".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("0.00".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("1,234567.10".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine("12,34567.00".IsMatch());
        Console.WriteLine(" ".IsMatch());

    }
}

public static class myRegexExtensions
{
    public static bool IsMatch(this string text)
    {
        var pattern = @"
  ^                # Work from the start of the line
 (?!.*[\w-[\d]])   # Don't allow any Alphanumerics (A-Za-z\d) but except digits \d
 (?=[\d.,]{0,12})  # Only allow for 0-12 digits or commas or periods
 (?!\d{8,})        # Stop match if eight consecutive digits found
 (?![\d,]{9,})     # Stop match if a combination of digits and commas exceeds 9
 [\s\d.]           # Allow for a space or a number period and consume it to the match.
 [\d,]{0,8}        # Should find numbers or a comma for up to 8 items
 .?                # A possible period
 \d{0,2}           # Two digits possible after the period
 \s?               # A space character (\r\n?) may be found or even an extra space (allowed per rules)
$    ";
        return Regex.IsMatch(text, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but how the combination should be on the basis of my requirement.

Comment: @neo Can you be more specific?

Comment: but how to combine the above given expressions as per my requirement.

Comment: @neo combine with what? This expression handles your requirements. Do you mean how to use it in code?

Comment: -1 This doesn't meet the requirements. It allows up to 9 comma-or-digit characters before the decimal point, but doesn't enforce that only 7 of them can be digits... so it will match `123456789.00`. Note that lookaheads only apply to the characters *immediately* following, so for example `^(?=\.{0,1})` means that `.` can be the **first** character, not that it can appear *anywhere* in the string.

Comment: @OmegaMan  I have geven the code in the textbox key down event but taking it  as shown in the question part .

Comment: @nmclean You were right about the 123456789.00. Added a negative look ahead to handle that situation.

Comment: @nmclean Also removed the superfluous positive lookaheads.

Comment: Still incorrect; it matches `1234567,8.00`. As I said in my answer, a rule of "*A* must appear up to *n* times *across* substring *B*" cannot be expressed as regex, without explicitly covering various combinations, which violates DRY. This already violates DRY by repeating the length rule 3 times (12, 8, 8).

Comment: @nmclean I do not disagree with the sentiments provided and mention two problems with the pattern above (comma placement and null). There are too many rules and comma processing should be handled in a _post_ step. My pattern provided simply catches more requirements of the user than any others provided up to this point.

Comment: @OmegaMan According to OP we don't need to worry about comma placement (`12,34567.00` is given as an acceptable format), but that's not what I'm talking about: the problem is that your pattern allows more than 7 digits. So we are going to need to re-verify the number of digits in a post step anyway, which means the attempt to do so in the pattern itself is redundant and only adds complexity. Removing the counting from the pattern entirely would be both more efficient and more maintainable.

Comment: @nmclean I updated the pattern to handle that scenario of more than seven digits, or do you know of a number which is causing it to fail?

Comment: @OmegaMan Yes, as I posted above: `1234567,8.00`. Or any other 8-digit number with a single comma anywhere within it.

Comment: @nmclean Done added to pattern to handle `1234567,8.00` and added it to the tests.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
^\d{1,7}\.?\d{0,2}$
```

should work for detecting right numbers.

for 'empty' value you can use separate test.

Answer (score 0):

May be, better(simpler) solution is to split string by decimal point, and then test left and right part separately.
Make almighty regex is not end in itself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe regular expressions alone is the tool for this. If the rule is *"up to 7 digits, with any number of commas interspersed among them"*, there is no way to express it with a regular expression. If you only want to allow the standard format of an optional comma every 3 digits, it's possible but would essentially involve listing the possible combinations:

```
(\d{0,3}|\d{1,3},?\d{0,3}|\d,?\d{1,3},?\d{0,3})
```

Which is very ugly, and painful to modify to a different requirement than 7 if you had to.

It would be much simpler to verify the format with this:

```
^([\d,]+)(\.\d{0,2})?$
```

Then do an additional verification on the first match group by counting the characters where [Char.IsDigit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0t641e58%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is true.